# UnavailableException() in Apache-Cassandra 0.8.2

Tags: java, cassandra

I new to Apache-Cassandra 0.8.2. I am trying to insert some data but getting this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" UnavailableException()
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$insert_result.read(Cassandra.java:14902)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_insert(Cassandra.java:858)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.insert(Cassandra.java:830)
    at TestCassandra.main(TestCassandra.java:166)
```

My Code is:

```
public class TestCassandra {

    public static void createKeySpace( Cassandra.Client client,String ksname)
        throws TException, InvalidRequestException, UnavailableException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NotFoundException, TimedOutException, SchemaDisagreementException {

        KsDef ksdef = new KsDef();
        ksdef.name = ksname;
        ksdef.strategy_class = "NetworkTopologyStrategy";    
        List l = new ArrayList();        
        ksdef.cf_defs =l;   

        client.system_add_keyspace(ksdef); 
        System.out.println("KeySpace Created");


    }

    public static void createColumnFamily(Cassandra.Client client,String ksname,String cfname)
        throws TException, InvalidRequestException, UnavailableException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NotFoundException, TimedOutException, SchemaDisagreementException {

        CfDef cfd = new CfDef(ksname, cfname);
        client.system_add_column_family(cfd);
        System.out.println("ColumnFamily Created");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws TException, InvalidRequestException, UnavailableException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NotFoundException, TimedOutException, SchemaDisagreementException {

        TTransport tr = new TFramedTransport(new TSocket("localhost", 9160));
        TProtocol proto = new TBinaryProtocol(tr);
        Cassandra.Client client = new Cassandra.Client(proto);
        tr.open();

       String keySpace = "Keyspace1";
       String columnFamily = "Users";

       //Drop the Keyspace 

       client.system_drop_keyspace(keySpace);

       //Creating keyspace


       KsDef ksdef = new KsDef();
       ksdef.name = keySpace;
       ksdef.strategy_class = "NetworkTopologyStrategy";    
       List l = new ArrayList();        
       ksdef.cf_defs =l;

       client.system_add_keyspace(ksdef); 
       System.out.println("KeySpace Created");

       //createKeySpace(client,keySpace);

       client.set_keyspace(keySpace);

       //Creating column Family

       CfDef cfd = new CfDef(keySpace, columnFamily);
       client.system_add_column_family(cfd);
       System.out.println("ColumnFamily Created");

       //createColumnFamily(client,keySpace,columnFamily);

       ColumnParent parent = new ColumnParent(columnFamily);

       Column description = new Column();
       description.setName("description".getBytes());
       description.setValue("I’m a nice guy".getBytes());
       description.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

       ConsistencyLevel consistencyLevel = ConsistencyLevel.ONE;
       ByteBuffer rowid = ByteBuffer.wrap("0".getBytes());

//Line No. 166
       client.insert(rowid, parent, description, consistencyLevel);
       System.out.println("Record Inserted...");

       tr.flush();       
       tr.close();
    }


}
```

Can anybody help me why this is so?

Comment: Your stack trace says the problem is on line 166. Your code snippet does not have line numbers. Therefore, you need to tell us what line 166 is because I am sure that your code snippet is not the entire file.

Comment: oh! sorry. The exception is on code 
client.insert(rowid, parent, description, consistencyLevel);

Comment: Suggestion: Use [Hector](http://prettyprint.me/2010/02/23/hector-a-java-cassandra-client/) client instead of directly playing with Thrift API. Your code will be cleaner and less error prone.

Comment: BTW, `UnavailableException` means `Not all the replicas required could be created and/or read.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the `UnavailableException` is due to the fact of in your `createKeySpace` method, you have never specified a `replication_factor` for your keyspace definition, `KsDef`.

The 2 Strategy class, `NetworkTopologyStrategy` and `SimpleStrategy` requires a replication factor to be set. In Cassandra 0.8 and higher, there is no more a `replication_factor` field in `KsDef` so you will have to add it yourself, like so (I've updated your code, but not tested. Also, see that I've changed your `strategy_class` to `SimpleStrategy`):

```
KsDef ksdef = new KsDef();
ksdef.name = ksname;
ksdef.strategy_class = SimpleStrategy.class.getName(); 

//Set replication factor
if (ksdef.strategy_options == null) {
    ksdef.strategy_options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
}

//Set replication factor, the value MUST be an integer
ksdef.strategy_options.put("replication_factor", "1");

//Cassandra must now create the Keyspace based on our KsDef
client.system_add_keyspace(ksdef);
```

For `NetworkTopologyStrategy`, you will need to specify your replication factor to each datacentre you've created (See explanation [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/operations/datacenter)).

For more information, view my [Interfacing with Apache Cassandra 0.8 in Java](http://theelitegentleman.blogspot.com/2011/08/interfacing-with-apache-cassandra-08-in.html) blog.

Comment: With NTS you must specify per-datacenter replica counts (that is the point of NTS). So unless you have a datacenter named replication_factor, this will not do what you want. This is such a common mistake that we added a special check for it in 0.8.3: ConfigurationException("replication_factor is an option for SimpleStrategy, not NetworkTopologyStrategy")

Comment: @jbellis. Thank you. It was not working because of i haven't specify any datacenter in ksdef.strategy_options. When I specify it, it works fine. check this: http://breiftechnews.blogspot.com/2011/08/simply-insert-data-in-apache-cassnadra.html

Comment: Anybody now how to insert Json string directly to Cassandra? Is there any way to this like client.insert(jsonString); ?

Comment: @Anand Soni, new question, new SO question! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Note that I ran in a similar problem (receiving many Unavailable exceptions) because I created a KsDef by code and inadvertently put 10 in there when I was testing on a cluster with only 3 nodes.

So the replication factor said 10 and thus attempting to do a QUORUM read or a QUORUM write would always fail because the QUORUM could never be reached (i.e. 10 / 2 + 1 = at least 6 nodes.)

Fixing my replication factor fixed all the problems with the QUORUM consistency level.